# (htaccess) Rewrite English names of php files to their Dutch equivalents

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I would like to rewrite the English names of php files to their Dutch equivalents.

For example: **someurl.com/news.php?readmore=4#comments** should become **someurl.com/nieuws.php?leesmeer=4#kommentaar**. The code from news.php should be executed but nieuws.php should be in the url the arguments should function as well.

I tried several htaccess examples but I can't get it to work.

Any help would be appreciated.

Edit: Working progress from answers below and final solution.

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^readmore=(.*)$
RewriteRule ^news.php$ nieuws.php?leesmeer=%1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !^norewrite[\w\W]*$
RewriteRule ^news.php$ nieuws.php [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^nieuws.php$ news.php?norewrite [QSA]

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !^norewrite[\w\W]*$
RewriteRule ^search.php$ zoeken.php [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^zoeken.php$ search.php?norewrite [QSA]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
# make sure rewrite is activ
RewriteEngine On 

# Rewrite a request for nieuws.php to news.php
RewriteRule ^nieuws.php$  news.php
```

Should do the trick.

Instad you could send all requests to an index.php and parse them there:

```
## Redirect everything to http://hostname/?path=requested/path
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^([\w\W]*)$  index.php?path=$1 [QSA]
```

[QSA] makes sure you get the original get arguments too.

Now you have to parse the request in $_GET['path'] in you index.php and `include` the requested page.

eg:

```
if ($_GET['path'] == 'nieuws.php') {
   include 'news.php';
} else if (empty($_GET['path'])) {
   echo "HOME";
}
```

if you want to make make the user always sees nieuws.php in its address bar, even if he requested news.php, you could try the following:

```
RewriteEngine On

# Redirect news.php to nieuws.php if and only if the request comes from the client
# (suppose the client didn't set ?norewrite.)
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !^norewrite[\w\W]*$
RewriteRule ^news.php$ nieuws.php [R=301,L]

# Send news.php if nieuws.php was requested and prevent news.php from being redirected
# to back to nieuws.php by the rule above.
RewriteRule ^nieuws.php$ news.php?norewrite [L,QSA]
```

(R=301 means send a "moved permanently" redirect to the client, L means stop rewriting after this rule matched)

The hole thing with norewrite (you could use something else instead) is only needed to avoid an endles loop of rewriting between news and nieuws.

To translate the GET arguments, you can try the following code before the first line of the above code:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^readmore=(.*)$
RewriteRule ^news.php$ nieuws.php?lesseer=%1 [R=301,L]
```

Things after a the # in an url can't be changed in .htaccess, since they aren't send to the server at all. The only chance to change them is using JavaScript. (See lots of question here on manipulating them within JavaScript)

Comment: Ok! RewriteRule ^nieuws.php$  news.php is working. Thanks! I can now open someurl.com/nieuws.php and someurl.com/news.php which is the same. But with this rewrite rule it does not change news.php in nieuws.php. I mean if I click an existing url like someurl.com/news.php?readmore=4#comments it doesn't rewrite to someurl.com/*nieuws*.php?readmore=4#comments  Is that possible?

Comment: Do you mean it doesn't display nieuws.php in the browser when you click on an link for news.php? In this case you need to send a redirect header to the browser.

Comment: No. How do I send a redirect header with htaccess?

Comment: Great! This is working. :) Thanks for your patience with me. Even someurl.com/nieuws.php?readmore=4#comments works. Any idea how to "translate" readmore/leesmeer and comments/kommentaar?

Comment: Repeat the same with all of them. Simply replace news by readmore and nieuws by leesmeer and so on.

Comment: Can't figure out how to go about nieuws.php?readmore=4#comments.  This won't work for other translations. `# Redirect news.php to nieuws.php if and only if the request comes from the client
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !^norewrite[\w\W]*$
RewriteRule ^news.php$ nieuws.php [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^nieuws.php$ news.php?norewrite [L,QSA]

# Redirect search.php to zoeken.php if and only if the request comes from the client
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !^norewrite[\w\W]*$
RewriteRule ^search.php$ zoeken.php [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^zoeken.php$ search.php?norewrite [L,QSA]`

Comment: Oh, I didn't see your new question, but I don't really the your point, anyway we shouldn't continue to discuss here.... Make sure you have the empty line after [R=301,L]. You can remove the comments (starting with #) if you want.

Comment: It solves the original question, but it partly solves my problem because it is not working (yet) for other urls and readmore/comments.

Comment: Sorry if I don't follow protocol, It's only my second question here.

Comment: You could also try to remove the L from all [L,QSA], so write [QSA] instad.

Comment: Yes this works fine. I have now someurl.com/nieuws.php and someurl.com/zoeken.php now I can also make the other php files! Still puzzle how to change readmore and comments in someurl.com/nieuws.php?readmore=4#comments

Comment: Ah. They are quite different, since the are part of the get arguments. You'll need to extract the values in a `RewriteRule` and use them in the redirection.

Comment: I've edited my question above with the code I have so far. What rewrite rule should I add to rewrite the arguments?

Comment: Ok. See edit. Could you update the Question to match the clarification you gave in the comments?

Comment: Did you see my edit concerning readmore? Does it work? If you want to change comments with JavaScript, please open a new question and close this one.

Comment: Yes. It is solved now!! At first I had an internal 500 error because of RedirectRule in your code. Changed this to RewriteCond and now I have the expected behavior. Thanks again for your patience and your support. :)

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /news\.php
RewriteRule ^ /nieuws.php [L,R=301,QSA]

RewriteRule ^nieuws\.php$ /news.php [L,QSA]
```

Comment: This works wonderfully! I can easily extend this for other "translations". RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /news\.php
RewriteRule ^ /nieuws.php [L,R=301,QSA]
RewriteRule ^nieuws\.php$ /news.php [L,QSA]

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /search\.php
RewriteRule ^ /zoeken.php [L,R=301,QSA]
RewriteRule ^zoeken\.php$ /search.php [L,QSA] Any idea how to "translate" readmore/leesmeer and comments/kommentaar?

Comment: @Karel If you're asking me about English/Dutch translations, I can't help you. But you if mean to translate the rule for `readmore/leesmeer` and `comments/kommentaar`, it's the same as you've done for `search/zoeken`.

Comment: @JonLin I mean news.php is now nieuws.php (that is ok) but I want to change readmore and comments to Dutch as well in:  someurl.com/nieuws.php?readmore=4#comments

Comment: @Karel Sorry, I can't answer a separate question in the comments, you can't format things in comments and it's exceedingly hard to figure out what you're trying to ask.

Comment: Ok thanks so far, your code works and helped me a lot. If I can't figure out my other question I'll make a new one here at stackoverflow.